# ORACLE AUTO INCREMENT jpa

Tags: jpa, oracle11g

i have prob with mapping sequence auto increment

@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)

i'm using on sql developer it work but when i try on netbeans i get the message

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sequence named `SOME_SEQ` in your db for this particular table. And use the annotations above your `id` field. `allocationSize=1` means increment the value by `1`. And `some_seq_gen_name` is for unique labeling.

```
@Id   
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(generator="some_seq_gen_name")
@SequenceGenerator(name="some_seq_gen_name", sequenceName="SOME_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
private Long id;
```

**UPDATE:** Based on your comment, for commit try this one:

```
EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
et.begin();
// write persist code here
et.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks , but when i do em.persist  it work  but  nothing  on table

Comment: i'm using em.flush();  but nothing